# Declaring a Global Multidimensional Array in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, global-variables, declaration

So, I'm trying to declare a 3-dimensional integer array globally so that it can be used by two separate functions.

Initially, I had tried this (`solns` being the name of the 3D array):

```
static int*** solns;
```

But while the triple pointer `solns` does persist between functions, the information I place inside of it does not.  This gives me a segfault when the second function tries to access data that the first function placed in `solns`.

How should I declare this such that the information inside remains?  I've tried

```
static int solns[][][];
```

among other things, but gcc doesn't like anything else I try.

EDIT: This snippet of code from function 1 places data into the array:

```
solns[k] = realloc(solns[k],sizeof(solns[k])/sizeof(int*)+sizeof(int*));
solns[k][l] = realloc(solns[k][l],sizeof(int)*4*sC);
    for(i=0;i<sC*4;i++)
    {
        solns[k][l][i] = row[i];
    }
    l++;
```

And this snippet is where function 2 tries to read that data:

```
if(solns[i][j][m*4+1]!=solns[i+1][n][m*4+2])
    break;
```

But `solns[i]` is a null pointer at that point because the data pointed to by `solns` doesn't carry over.

Comment: Please show a minimal code example that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Okay, Done.  Hopefully it makes some sense without the remainder of the code attached.

Comment: You havent done something silly like define a function local variable with the exact same name have you?

Comment: This *not* a 3D integer array that you are declaring. This is an emulation of such a thing and you should avoid this in modern C if you can and allocate just contiguous arrays.

Comment: do you ever allocate memory for solns? I can see you allocating for solns[k] and solns[k][l] but never for solns itself.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the term `static` in global scope, it means that the instance of that object/variable is local to each compilation unit.

This means that each `.cpp` file will have a different version of the above variable. Thus if your functions are in 2 different files, it will not work.

To fix this, define this variable in a `.cpp` file and declare it as a `extern` in a header file.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but both functions are in the same file, so I don't think that applies.

Comment: .cpp files are for C++ and not for C

Answer (score 1):

If you use `static int ***solns` you'd have to allocate memory for the array. All that is allocated in that case is space for one pointer to a memory address that holds an `int **`. If you use `static int solns[][][]` you need to give a size such as `static int solns[4][5][3]`